# How to include machina.js into a node.js application

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, machina.js

I want to start learning how to use Machina.js but I simply can not get it to work. According to the documentation I should be able to include Machina with

```
var lodash = require('lodash');
var machina = require('machina')(lodash);
```

but I get the following error.

```
var machina = require('machina')(lodash);
                                 ^
TypeError: object is not a function
```

I noticed that I should also be able to use

```
var machina = require('machina')();
```

and underscore will be used instead of lodash, but I get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use current version (1.1.1), just

```
var machina = require('machina');
```

then you can start use it: http://code.dougneiner.com/presentations/machina/#session/1/slide/17

Comment: Thanks for helping a noob out. I knew it had to be something super simple.... as you can probably tell I'm fairly new to Node haha